# Сложный реляционный запрос через Yii AR

Tags: activerecord, php, yii, mysql

В MySQL-базе данных имеется 4 таблицы:

```
clients
client_info (client_id, service_id, action_id)
services
actions
```

где таблица client_info (в скобках указаны названия столбцов, в которых хранятся ID записей из соответствующих таблиц) является "связующим звеном" между остальными тремя. Задача следующая: получить все услуги (services) и действия (actions) конкретного клиента (clients) таким образом, чтобы, выбрав клиента по PK, можно было получить все его действия по связи $client->services->actions.
Как это сделать?

Не могу найти решение уже третий день, хотя вроде бы задача не сложная.

Comment: Вообще дополнительные поля в таблице связей - это краеугольный камень первой Yii, однако если у вас есть связь сервисы -> actions, то у вас что-то неправильно с БД.

Comment: $client->services->actions в текущем формате БД вы не выведите никогда (как уже выше написал @Etki), а вот для каждого сервиса $client->services можно вывести действия $client->actions и наоборот

Comment: @Etki, работаю с уже созданной предыдущими разработчиками моделью данных, и, к сожалению, менять её не могу. Собственно поэтому и возникают подобные проблемы.
@MasterAlex, приведённый вами пример мной уже опробован, но в этом случае сортировку придётся перекладывать на скрипт, чего я так хотел избежать. Однако, пока что это единственный вариант. Спасибо.